# Как правильно наклонить объект по X и Z, имея направление

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть задачи: мне нужно наклонять торс (по факту одну из костей) персонажа в направлении получаемого удара, сам удар может быть с любой стороны вокруг персонажа на плоскости. Грубо говоря, ринг.

Я подумал, что раз уж есть направление удара и есть функция Quaternion.LookRotation, которая возвращает поворот по направлению, то стало быть всё просто. В общем, саму механику наклона я реализовал, но как оказалось, Quaternion.LookRotation возвращает кватернион с нулевым углом по Z. С точки зрения логики я догадался, почему так происходит: осей X и Y достаточно, что бы указать направление из точки в любую сторону, но на деле мне нужно наклонять по Х и Z, и очень не нужно поворачивать кость по Y. Соответственно, я её обнуляю, но тогда остается только наклон по Х. И, как вы могли догадаться, это приводит к тому, что при ударе торс персонажа просто всегда откидывает назад по Х, независимо откуда наносится удар.
Само же направление ударов вычисляется правильно, я рисовал лучи дебогом и убедился в этом, но вот корректно перевести направление в углы Z и X никак не удается.

**Собственно, вопрос:** как же мне всё так просчитать, что бы персонаж наклонялся по X и/или по Z в зависимости от того, с какой стороны пришелся удар (спереди, сбоку, со спины, по диагонали и т.д.)?

Скрипт того, что у меня сейчас, ниже, но на всякий случай оговорюсь, что он должен работать поверх Аниматора, поэтому там LateUpdate и приплюсовывание дефолтного rotation в каждом фрейме. Но саму кость анимации двигают не более чем на 5 градусов, и то это делает только одна из них, поэтому это не может влиять.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyKickbacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _kickbackingBone;

    private EnemyFighter _thisFighter;
    private PlayerFighter _opponentFighter;

    private float _returnSpeed = 4f;
    private float _kickbackingDepth = 2f;

    private Quaternion _generalTilt = new Quaternion();
    private Quaternion _kickbackingTilt = new Quaternion();

    private Coroutine _returningToDefault;



    private void Start()
    {
        CombatEventsManager.Instance.OnDamageDealing += Kickbacking;

        _thisFighter = GetComponent<Fighter>() as EnemyFighter;
        _opponentFighter = _thisFighter.Opponent as PlayerFighter;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (_returningToDefault == null) return;

        _generalTilt = Quaternion.Euler(_kickbackingBone.rotation.eulerAngles + _kickbackingTilt.eulerAngles);
        //Debug.LogFormat("Default {0}, kickback {1}, general {2}", _kickbackingBone.rotation.eulerAngles, _kickbackingTilt.eulerAngles, _generalTilt.eulerAngles);
        _kickbackingBone.rotation = _generalTilt;
    }


    private void Kickbacking(Fighter victim, int damage)
    {
        if (victim != (Fighter)_thisFighter) return;

        if (_returningToDefault == null)
        {
            _returningToDefault = StartCoroutine(ReturnToDefaultAngle());
        }
        else
        {
            StopCoroutine(_returningToDefault);
            _returningToDefault = StartCoroutine(ReturnToDefaultAngle());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ReturnToDefaultAngle()
    {
        float step = 0f;
        Vector3 selfPos = new Vector3(_thisFighter.transform.position.x, _kickbackingDepth, _thisFighter.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 opponentPos = new Vector3(_opponentFighter.transform.position.x, 0f, _opponentFighter.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 direction = (selfPos - opponentPos).normalized;
        Quaternion startTilt = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        Quaternion finalTilt = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);

        startTilt = Quaternion.Euler(startTilt.eulerAngles.x, 0f, startTilt.eulerAngles.z);
        //Debug.LogFormat("forward direction {0}, hit direction {1}", transform.forward, direction);
        
        while (step <= 1f)
        {
            _kickbackingTilt = Quaternion.Slerp(startTilt, finalTilt, step);
            step += _returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }        

        _returningToDefault = null;
    }
}
```

Я пробовал инвертировать direction в локальное пространство и множить полученный после LookRotation угол X (даже не буду тратить наше время, что бы это объяснить, но в какой-то момент мне показалось это логичным):

```
startTilt = Quaternion.Euler(Mathf.Abs(startTilt.eulerAngles.x) * direction.z, 0f, Mathf.Abs(startTilt.eulerAngles.x) * direction.x);
```

Потом нашел как получить по направлению отдельно какой-то угол и переписал вычисление углов в такой вид:

```
        float step = 0f;
        Vector3 selfPos = new Vector3(_thisFighter.transform.position.x, _kickbackingDepth, _thisFighter.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 opponentPos = new Vector3(_opponentFighter.transform.position.x, 0f, _opponentFighter.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 direction = (selfPos - opponentPos).normalized;

        direction = _kickbackingBone.InverseTransformDirection(direction);

        float angleZ = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float angleX = Mathf.Atan2(direction.z, direction.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        
        Quaternion startTilt = Quaternion.Euler(angleX, 0f, angleZ);
        Quaternion finalTilt = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Тоже не то. И каждый из результатов был слишком кривой. Самое близкое к сути, на удивление, дало простое добавление второго параметра LookRotation(direction, Vector3.forward), но с некоторых сторон торс врага всё-равно откидывало не в направлении удара, даже не близко. Поиграв с этим параметром, закидывая туда разные нормализованные вектора, я так и не понял что конкретно он делает и что туда надо передать для достижения желаемого. Но почему-то мне кажется, что это и не должно сработать.

В общем, у меня пока закончились идеи и никак не могу понять в какую сторону двигаться, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Чувство, будто это всё делается не сложно и решение где-то на поверхности, но я недопонимаю чего-то элементарного

P.S. если какое-то из моих решений вам показалось правильным и оно теоретически должно работать - сообщите об этом, возможно больше внимания и пару небольших правок привели бы их к рабочему виду.

Comment: "осей X и Y достаточно, что бы указать направление из точки в любую сторону" -- это как так достаточно двухмерного пространства что бы задавать позицию в трехмерном?

Comment: @Andrew я ж не про вектор говорил, а про углы. Если вы вытянете руку вперед и будете вращаться всем телом на месте (ось Y), а руку поднимать вверх-вниз (ось X), то сможете направить её в любом направлении в трехмерном пространстве. В этой ситуации Z это выкручивание руки вокруг своей оси, оно попросту не определяется вектором направления. Поэтому LookRotation либо не подходит вовсе, либо надо делать что-то извращенное как в моей первой правке

Comment: Даже если так, то там бы возвращали Vector2, а не Vector3. А раз возвращают 3 - то на это есть причина - туда могут приходить данные. Из документации "`Creates a rotation with the specified forward and upwards directions. Z axis will be aligned with forward, X axis aligned with cross product between forward and upwards, and Y axis aligned with cross product between Z and X.`" - то есть Z может изменятся в случае если тебе нужен поворот относительно некоего направления. Он не всегда равен нулю. И, вполне возможно, что тебе для решения вопроса именно этого и не хватает.

Comment: @Andrew что-то никак не пойму как это выглядит на практике и как это надо использовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, всё решилось намного проще, даже не знаю почему я об этом не подумал раньше. Самая странная и простая попытка решить проблему в конце концов оказалась почти правильной.
Я просто обнулил в вычислении направления величину по Y, а вместо метода LookRotation напрямую указываю угол. Поле _kickbackingDepth стало не высотой в вычислениях направления, а этим углом, на который надо наклонять. Код приобрел такой вид:

```
float step = 0f;
Vector3 selfPos = new Vector3(_thisFighter.transform.position.x, 0f, _thisFighter.transform.position.z);
Vector3 opponentPos = new Vector3(_opponentFighter.transform.position.x, 0f, _opponentFighter.transform.position.z);
Vector3 direction = (selfPos - opponentPos).normalized;
direction = _kickbackingBone.InverseTransformDirection(direction);

Quaternion startTilt = Quaternion.Euler(_kickbackingDepth * direction.z, 0f, _kickbackingDepth * -direction.x);
Quaternion finalTilt = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Вряд ли смогу правильно объяснить почему решил умножать на направление. Наверное что-то в духе: направление содержит величины по Х и Z, и наклонять надо тоже по этим осям. А поскольку вектор нормализирован (величины от -1 до 1), то он вполне сойдет за процентный множитель, которым можно задать сторону и глубину наклона для каждой нужной мне оси. Единственное, пришлось поменять местами множители x и z, потому что направление вперед/назад в локальных координатах определяется по оси Z, но наклоны торса вперед/назад осуществляются по оси Х. Ну и минус добавил, потому что отрицательное направление по Х, это положительный наклон по Z.